# Return rows where the count of a character is?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, stored-procedures

I'm developing a rudimentary word finder app with sql and ruby where I have an array of letters to find available words.  It's easier to make the query by narrowing down what alphabetic letters aren't in the array. For ex.

```
alphabet= %w{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z}

available_letters = %w{p k z l p m t l n g g r u a r t n d z w a l m n e}
```

I can then subtract from alphabet, letters to exclude from my search and end up with an sql query like the one below.

```
select * from words
where word not like '%b%' and word not like '%c%' and word not like '%f%'.....
```

This gives me all the available words with a combination of all available letters.  It does not narrow them down by the number of times that letter occurs.  So if I only have one "E",  I would like the query to narrow down words that only contain one e.  I'm not sure if this can be done with an sql query or whether I will need to use a procedure.  Anyone know a good way of solving this?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a - 26 column (I know that sounds terrible) - table with the letter counts available? Then all you'd have to do is: `SELECT * FROM words WHERE e=1` - which would be HELLA faster by the way

Comment: I suppose you could create a junction table populated by word_id, letter_id, count ... such that the entry for "populated,p" would contain 2 in the count column while "populated,e" would have a count of 1 (as would the others in that word).  Such a table would have n-entries per word, one entry for every distinct letter in that word.  (Populated would have 8 entries in the junction/count table).

That would give about a half-million entries for 50K works averaging 10 distinct characters each.  Sounds a bit ugly but it does effectively trade off precompute and space for quick normalized lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look into faster ways of implementing this, but to answer your question, you can exclude words with more than one "e" with `not like '%e%e%'`.

Comment: I like the suggestions in the comments on your question.  You might also look at breaking up your query into a bunch of queries that only look at the starts of words, which is potentially much faster if your database has a tree-based index.